# AutoHotkey: Remap Alt + Tab to behave like Win + T

Tags: replace, macros, autohotkey

The code below works, with two things I cant figure out how to fix:
1. Default Win + Tab behavior is broken. 
2. The Thumbnails are cycled in the wrong order. How could I keep the script as it is now, but also add another shortcut combination (say Alt + `) to cycle in the correct order.

BTW: I have added an {Enter} after Alt is realeased, so the script automatically activates the desired window.

```
$*Tab::
WinActivate, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd  ;this is used to bring focus out of the current window
Getkeystate, Laltstate, Lalt, P
if Laltstate = D
{
   Send {Blind}{LAlt up}{LWin down}{T}
   ifequal FixB, 0, Send {T}
   FixB = 1
}
else
   Send {Blind}{T}
return

~$*LAlt up::
Send {Blind}{Lwin up}{Enter}
FixB = 0
return
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what `FixB` is doing. Care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

You say that this works, but I would expect your <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to always produce a `T` unless the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is down. If you try to insert a tab within a Notepad document, I would expect you to instead type `T`.

`$*Tab::` indicates that hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> will trigger this hotkey, no matter what else is held down. Thus, when you hold down the <kbd>Win</kbd> key and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, you're sending `Win`+`T` instead with your `else Send {Blind}{T}` code.

You are cycling in reverse order because you're using an upper-case `T` in your `Send` statement. `Send T` or `Send {T}` are sending `t` along with shift, which reverses the order. Just send `t` instead, and you'll go in the correct order.